# Drop down using Jquery plugin select2

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I have a drop down that uses Jquery plugin Select2. The drop down works fine. The issue is that I have several drop downs that uses Select2 plugin . All these drop downs have the same class name. I dont want to repeat the Jquery code for all these drop downs. Below is what I have:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#ddlSection").select2({
    tags: true,
    createTag: function(params) {
      return {
        id: params.term,
        text: params.term,
        newOption: true
      }
    },
    templateResult: function(data) {
      var $result = $("<span></span>");

      $result.text(data.text);

      if (data.newOption) {
        $result.append(" <em>(new)</em>");
      }

      return $result;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.13/dist/css/select2.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.13/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<select id="ddlSection" class="form-control ddlvalue">
  <option value="0">--Select Sections--</option>
  <option value="6">Test1</option>
  <option value="20">Test2</option>
</select>

<select id="ddlCustomer" class="form-control ddlvalue">
  <option value="0">--Select Customer--</option>
  <option value="6">Test3</option>
  <option value="20">Test4</option>
</select>
```

I don't want to repeat the same Jquery code for ddlCustomer and other drop downs that I have on my web page. How can I use the className for these dropdowns instead of Id so that I don't need to repeat the code for each drop down. Below is the screen shot of the ddlsection drop down using select2 jQuery plugin:

[image]

any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Simply `$('.ddlvalue')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$('.ddlvalue').select2({....})`;